# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: javafx.scene.image.Image, at table: PRODUCT

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

I am working on a selling application, i am using Jpa and hibernate
how to fix this error: " org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: javafx.scene.image.Image, at table: PRODUCT, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(picture)]"

my class product

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT", schema = "ROOT" )
public class Product {

private SimpleIntegerProperty productId;
private SimpleStringProperty productName;
private Image picture;
private Date addingDate;
// ....

}


public Product() {

    this.productId = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    this.productName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    
}

/* getters and setters */
@Column(name= "picture")
public Image getPicture() {
    return this.picture;
}

public void setPicture(Image picture) {
    
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(picture.getUrl());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {   System.out.println(e.getMessage());   }
        
    picture = new Image(stream);
    
    this.picture = picture;
}
```

Comment: You can't just use a javafx image class in an JPA/Hibernate entity. Not every existing java class has a default mapping in JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS thanks

Answer (score 0):

after I found the solution to the problem based on what he said
@oh-god-spiders above, I want to share it with you

**1.** don't use

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

private Image picture;
```

you have to use byte type like this:

```
private byte[] picture;
```

so

```
/* getters and setters */

@Column(name= "picture")
public byte[] getPicture() {
    return this.picture;
}

public void setPicture(byte[] picture) {
    
    this.picture = picture;
}
```

see this tutorial in :

[Retrieve and Save Images in Database using Hibernate](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Retrieve-and-Save-Images-in-Database-using-Hibernate/)

**2.**
if you want to change byte to image

```
byte[] pictureImageInByte = product.getPicture();

ByteArrayInputStream imageDate = new ByteArrayInputStream(pictureImageInByte);
            
Image image = new Image(imageDate);
```

see more in this question: [conversion d'un byteArray[] en image](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d2092966/java/interfaces-graphiques-java/javafx/conversion-d-bytearray-image/)